# Jenkins: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'within' Build

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a python script that I tested on an EC2 instance, which works perfectly fine on the server but when I try to pass the same parameters from Jenkins job as shown below. I get the error message:

> > Security Group Created **sg-ca09bcae** in vpc **vpc-d79691b9**. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./create_sg.py", line 32, in 
> >         'FromPort': int(FROM_PORT_1.strip("")), 
> >     marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'within' Build
> >     step 'Execute shell'

[image: Jenkins Job Parameters]

I'm pretty sure the error is because of the string parameter that I'm passing through Jenkins parameters but there isn't an option to send both From and To ports as integers in jenkins parameters.

How can I set the parameters to an integer within Jenkins build job?

Python code to create SG:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
region = "us-west-1"

VPC_ID=sys.argv[1]
SECURITY_GROUP_NAME=sys.argv[2]
DESCRIPTION=sys.argv[3]
IP_PROTOCOL_1=sys.argv[4]
FROM_PORT_1=sys.argv[5]
TO_PORT_1=sys.argv[6]
CIDR_IP_1=sys.argv[7]


ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2.describe_vpcs()

vpc_id = VPC_ID

try:
    response = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName=SECURITY_GROUP_NAME,Description=DESCRIPTION,VpcId=VPC_ID)
    security_group_id = response['GroupId']
    print('Security Group Created %s in vpc %s.' % (security_group_id, vpc_id))

    data = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId=security_group_id,
        IpPermissions=[
            {'IpProtocol': IP_PROTOCOL_1,
             'FromPort': int(FROM_PORT_1.strip("")),
             'ToPort': int(TO_PORT_1.strip("")),
             'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': CIDR_IP_1}]}
        ]
    )
    print('Ingress Successfully Set %s' % data)
except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: What's the output of `TO_PORT_1.strip("")`?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the description as separated parameters

```
VPC_ID=sys.argv[1] # -> vpc-d79691b9
SECURITY_GROUP_NAME=sys.argv[2] # -> Security_Group_Test_Dev
DESCRIPTION=sys.argv[3] # -> Security
IP_PROTOCOL_1=sys.argv[4] # -> group
FROM_PORT_1=sys.argv[5] # within
TO_PORT_1=sys.argv[6] # dev
CIDR_IP_1=sys.argv[7] # environment
```

That means the variable `FROM_PORT_1` contains `'within'` which is not an integer.

Somewhere in your stack, when your script is called, it is using space to split parameters, and the description is leaking to the other parameters.

You can check that my assumptions are correct by using a single-word description instead.

You should fix it in the part that calls python code, but if you can't fix that, here's how to work around that error with python code:

```
VPC_ID=sys.argv[1] 
SECURITY_GROUP_NAME=sys.argv[2]
DESCRIPTION=' '.join(sys.argv[3:-4])
IP_PROTOCOL_1=sys.argv[-4]
FROM_PORT_1=sys.argv[-3]
TO_PORT_1=sys.argv[-2] 
CIDR_IP_1=sys.argv[-1]
```

Comment: Partially worked the Port that I defined within Jenkins parameters is 22 and the port that I'm seeing within the AWS console is 0.

Comment: How can I pass the port numbers for To and From port? With the solution you recommended, I see that the ports are listed as 0 even after we pass different values via the parameters.